# completableFuture task should execute independently with main method task

Tags: java, io, stream, completable-future

If i call future.get() for every completableFuture task, then only my functionality works fine to write multiple files simultaneously.
But if i remove future.get() code then it is not working fine to write multiple files.For that i should add future.get() code.

FYI i am calling below method from main method but what happens here is that until all tasks being completed by calling method, my main method thread also wait to complete and stop to execute other code of main method.
But my purpose is that it should call other code in main thread and calling method should work asynchronously. It should not impact my main method code.
So can you help me to implement as per my requirement.

Below is code for the same:-

```
  private static void createCompletableFuture(ByteArrayOutputStream baOS, int totalBytes, 
            List<FileUploadMultiLocator> fileUploadList) {
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        for (FileUploadMultiLocator fileUploadMultiLocator : fileUploadList) {
            CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->{
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " secondary task is called");
                fileUploadMultiLocator.baOS.write(baOS.toByteArray(), 0, totalBytes);
                fileUploadMultiLocator.setTotalBytes(totalBytes);
                threadPool.execute(fileUploadMultiLocator);
                 return 20;
            },threadPool);
            try {
                 future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        threadPool.shutdown();
        try {
            threadPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return;
    }
```

Comment: Create a `List<CompletableFuture<Integer>>` then call [`CompletableFuture.allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)) after you have created all your uploads. Now you can call `get` on that `CompletableFuture` when you are ready to wait for all tasks to complete. Currently your code is **synchronous** as you wait for each task! You need to start all tasks and then wait for them all to complete.

Comment: The main thread is getting blocked because you call `awaitTermination()`. Just call `shutdown()` and return from the method (and remove that explicit `return`).

Comment: @Kayaman
I have tried to remove awaitTermination() and return statement.
Main thread is not getting blocked due to awaitTermination().
Something else is the reason.

Comment: Well the `future.get()` blocks also, but I thought you understood and removed that?

Comment: @Kayaman
Yes i have tried with removal of future.get() also but as i have already said after removal of future.get(), it is not working properly while writing the bytes.
Without writing to files, it completes the task.

Comment: Oh you're passing the `ByteArrayOutputStream` as a parameter...and all your threads seem to be writing to a different stream at the same time. The code is so bad and confusing that I'd delete all that and start over. Maybe think what you want to achieve first. Why do you pass an executor as a parameter **and** create an executor inside the method? You can't program just by putting things together and hope they work.

Comment: **Why do you pass an executor as a parameter and create an executor inside the method? **
It was an mistake. Actually executor passing in method parameter is not used

Comment: @Kayaman
**Maybe think what you want to achieve first**
I want to achieve 2 things as below:-
1. Main method reading a single file and writing it to ByteArrayOutputStream baOS and passing that baOS to other method (e.g.createCompletableFuture method).
2. Main method should do its work ahead and don't wait for createCompletableFuture method task completes

Comment: @Kayaman
So main method should read a file and write it to only one location which is primary location.
& other method createCompletableFuture parallelly should write same stream to multiple files asynchronously which are secondary locations.

Comment: Fair enough. Run it through a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: It's written in a confusing scrambled way, like if you had very little idea on what you're coding and you've pasted snippets of code together. Why on earth are you calling `threadPool.execute()` manually? Why do you have 2 executors? Go read a `CompatibleFuture` tutorial, because you obviously have no idea what you've written.

Comment: My purpose is to achieve below things:-
1. A single file should upload on 3 locations. One is primary and other 
   two are secondary locations.
2.We want response from primary location only so file should be uploaded on primary location first.
3. As soon as file upload done on primary location, i should get response from that.
4.For secondary locations upload, it should process in background and it should not impact on primary location file upload performance

So i have taken above approach for secondary locations.

Comment: @Kayaman
Thanks for your all support. Let me look CompatibleFuture in details

Comment: @Kayaman
I have implemented completable future successfully but just came to know that on secondary locations, it looks like file content is different even though file size is same for all files. 
So i think due to threading, it writes bytes randomly and not sequentially so it could achieve the same size file upload but file content is differ for all. Do you have idea about why its happening?

Answer (score 0):

you made asynchronous calls in your  createCompletableFuture  method, but I guess you are calling this method from main thread that's why your main thread waits to createCompletableFuture return. Call this method from main method using another thread.